# Material UI Icons are not showing up correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, google-material-icons

I am moving my React app inside an angular app and have got everything working except for the material-ui/icons
They are there, they just do not look as they should!
for example:
[material-ui/icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHB2y.png)

Would anyone know what is going on here? I'm using the most current packages I have the link tag in my index.html file `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">`
and I believe I'm using the Icons correctly.

`import { Close } from '@material-ui/icons'`

`<Close />`

Comment: I am not sure exactly where the issue is but I made a small react example of material ui icons here: https://codesandbox.io/s/0xvnx1rqy0

Comment: thank you @BrandonR that's exactly how I did it and they are still not working right. Strange... Thank you though!